# Custom WS directory in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I try to create a new directory in Laravel project  and i can't access to **DB facede**
Please how can i make it work.

**This is my code**

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
$results = DB::table('airports')->get();
```

**Path** : 
root/ws

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` to `use DB;`

Also add namespace `<?php namespace Root\WS;`

Comment: THank you for your response , but same problem here , i think laravel dont take the new directory in considiration

Comment: I don't have access to Apache but it's HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: You can check the error in your laravel logs inside your storage/logs folder, did you tried add the namespace?